# Is it possible to add libstdc to arduino-ide

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I'm using TensorFlow lite and it need to include the libstdc mode specifically cstddef but the Arduino IDE is not able to fine any of the libstdc.
I know they are installed because i searcher in the PC and they are in /usr/include/c++/8.

if i change the cstddef in stddef.h it work flawlessly.

home/jan/Arduino/libraries/hello_world/src/third_party/flatbuffers/include/flatbuffers/base.h:31:19: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need any component of libstdc at all:

> from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/microcontrollers/overview
>
> TensorFlow Lite for Microcontrollers
>
> TensorFlow Lite for Microcontrollers is an experimental port of TensorFlow Lite aimed at microcontrollers and other devices with only kilobytes of memory.
>
> It is designed to be portable even to "bare metal" systems, so it doesn't require operating system support, any standard C or C++ libraries, or dynamic memory allocation

Also:

- If you write code for Arduino, what you can find in /usr/include/..., is VERY RARELY what you're searching for, because that stuff is meant to compile for your computer, not a microcontroller
- Arduino has it's own library tree and library manager, you should always start by checking these
- Then, only if you are REALLY SURE to need a libstdc++ implementation for Arduino, you want to check this: https://cxx.uclibc.org/faq.html